# Change ID3D11Texture2D pixel format

Tags: directx, textures, direct3d, directx-11

I have texture, loaded from a .DDS file using the method **D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile()**. The DDS is created using Block Compression 1 compression, so when I query *IDXGISurface1* from the *ID3D11Texture2D*, the pixel format of the surface is DXGI_FORMAT_BC1_UNORM.

So my question is: can I change (convert) the format of the surface to DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM. I tried [ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476392%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  method but it seems it is unable to convert from BC1 to 32bppBGRA.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If it's just a one-off, you can convert and save in the required fromat using `DxTex.exe`

Comment: Full screen quad (or full screen triangle) + rendertarget is pretty much the only way to go (or small compute shader, but I doubt it will be better than pixel shader in your use case, likely slower). CopyResource won't work since it's like a direct copy, not a conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a one-time or build-time process, use the [TexConv](http://directxtex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Texconv) tool included in [DirectXTex](http://directxtex.codeplex.com/releases/view/112907).  If you need to do this at run-time, you can either render the image to a B8G8R8A8 render target, or use the CPU conversion code included in the DirectXTex library.

Comment: I need to do this conversion at run time, and I will need to use the GPU for better performance. Looks like the only way is to assign the texture to a quad, and then render a 3d scene. I will post the results when I try this.